# How to create Profile user page using asp.net mvc 4 with sql server 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I want to ask about create profile user page using asp.net mvc 4 and sql server 2008. Before i ask about it. I have create source code in controller  like this:

```
namespace SIDLubricants.Controllers
{
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    private Tugas_AkhirEntities db = new Tugas_AkhirEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Profile/

    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        var m_cp_customer = from cp in db.M_cp_Customer.Include(m => m.User) where cp.Id == model.Id select cp;
        return View(m_cp_customer.ToList());
```

**and i have create view like this :**

```
<div id="content" class="span12">
<div class="row-fluid sortable">
            <div class="box span12">
                <div class="box-header well">
                    <h2>Contact Person Profile</h2>
                   <table>
                       <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
                       <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                       <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Contact Person Customer") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.kd_cp_customer) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("First Name") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NamaDepan) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Last Name") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NamaBelakang) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Birth Date") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tgl_Lahir) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Gender") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JenisKelamin) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Address") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Alamat) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("City") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Kota) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Province") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Provinsi) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Zip Code") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KodePos) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Phone") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telp) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Mobile") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mobile) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("Email") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayName("UserName") %></td>
                           <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.userName) %></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td><input type="button" onclick="" value="edit" /></td>
                           <td> <input type="submit" value="Delete" /></td>
                       </tr>

                       <% } %>
                   </table>

                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->

        </div><!--/row-->
```

but, i got an error message like this:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SIDLubricants.Models.M_cp_Customer]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SIDLubricants.Models.M_cp_Customer'
```

Can you help me about it. I want final output is show all of data about profile user after action log in. Thank you...

Comment: So did you read the error message? It says right there what's wrong. Your view expects a single instance of `SIDLubricants.Models.M_cp_Customer` but in your controller you do `ToList()`, generating a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not SQL Server 2008, the problem is that you're returning zero or more entities that match the user's id. You need to add `FirstOrDefault()` to your query so you're not returning a `IEnumerable<M_cp_Customer>` but a single `M_cp_Customer` entity.

```
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
    M_cp_Customer m_cp_customer = (from cp in db.M_cp_Customer.Include(m => m.User) 
                                   where cp.Id == model.Id 
                                   select cp).FirstOrDefault();

    return View(m_cp_customer);
}
```

Comment: thank you CornéM.. sorry, i am new in asp.net so i still confuse if my source code error.. i using tittle problem is SQL Server 2008 because i developed this application using asp.net mvc 4 and sql server 2008. :)

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project and learning ASP.NET!